# C++ Implicit conversion from bool to string

Tags: c++

I have the following code, which compiles in Visual C++ 2012.

```
#include <string>

void func(std::string str)
{
}

void my_func()
{
    func(false);
}
```

The boolean 'false' is implicity passed into the string constructor

```
string(const char* _Ptr)
```

And then the pointer is null (because false = 0). Why does this compile, and should it compile according to the C++11 standard?

Comment: That shouldn't compile.

Comment: Only the literal `0` can be a null pointer constant. This shouldn't compile indeed.

Comment: Interestingly it doesn't compile if you pass 'true'

Comment: Surprisingly GCC compiles it too, but not without spewing "warning: converting 'false' to pointer type for argument 1 of [...] [-Wconversion-null]"

Comment: You can see GCC compiling and running it [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/14dfdab429858113) and [here](https://ideone.com/1LSv8U)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MSVC is mistakenly treating `false` as a null pointer constant. However, according to N4140, §4.10 [conv.ptr]/1 (emphasis mine):

> A null pointer constant is an **integer literal** with value zero
>   or a **prvalue of type std::nullptr_t**. A null pointer constant can be
>   converted to a pointer type; the result is the null pointer value of
>   that type and is distinguishable from every other value of object
>   pointer or function pointer type.

The wording changed a bit from C++11, and you can [find that discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17501942/962089). The verdict there was that it was an error in C++11 as well.

For visibility, TartanLlama provided the definition of "integer literal" below, according to [lex.icon]/1:

> An integer literal is a sequence of digits that has no period or exponent part, with optional separating single quotes that are ignored when determining its value.

Comment: I believe you are wrong because `bool` is an integral type (§3.9.1/7)

Comment: @KonradRudolph `bool` is an integral type, but `false` is not an integer literal.

Comment: @TartanLlama How so? It’s an integer and it’s a literal, and its value is 0.

Comment: @KonradRudolph [lex.icon]/1 "An integer literal is a sequence of digits that has no period or exponent part, with optional separating single
quotes that are ignored when determining its value."